# Concatenate Two Dataframes Pandas with single Row

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like:

```
   one  three  two
0  1.0   10.0  4.0
1  2.0    3.0  3.0
2  3.0   22.0  2.0
3  4.0    1.0  1.0
```

I have another single row dataframe `df2` that looks like:

```
     a    b    m    u
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
```

I want to concatenate the two to end up with:

```
   one  three  two    a    b    m    u
0  1.0   10.0  4.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0    3.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
2  3.0   22.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
3  4.0    1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
```

I tried:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

     0     1    2    3    4    5    6
0  1.0  10.0  4.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0   3.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  3.0  22.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  4.0   1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Err Wrong answer...

How can I sort this out?

Many thanks.

Comment: How a bout `df.join(df2).ffill()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for repeat data:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df2.values, len(df.index)).reshape(-1,len(df2.columns)), 
                   columns=df2.columns)
print (df2)
     a    b    m    u
0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
1  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
2  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
3  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0

df3 = df.join(df2)
print (df3)
   one  three  two    a    b    m    u
0  1.0   10.0  4.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0    3.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
2  3.0   22.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
3  4.0    1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
```

Or improved [John Galt solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714140/concatenate-two-dataframes-pandas-with-single-row/45714263#comment78386650_45714140) - only replaced `NaN`s of columns from `df2`:

```
df3 = df.join(df2)
df3[df2.columns] = df3[df2.columns].ffill()
print (df3)
   one  three  two    a    b    m    u
0  1.0   10.0  4.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0    3.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
2  3.0   22.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
3  4.0    1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
```

Another solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) by `Series` created by `iloc`, but columns names has to be strings:

```
df3 = df.assign(**df2.iloc[0])
print (df3)
   one  three  two    a    b    m    u
0  1.0   10.0  4.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0    3.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
2  3.0   22.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
3  4.0    1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(44)
N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1, 50)))
df2.columns = 'a' + df2.columns.astype(str)


In [369]: %timeit df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.tile(df2.values, len(df.index)).reshape(-1,len(df2.columns)), columns=df2.columns))
1 loop, best of 3: 897 ms per loop

In [370]: %timeit df.assign(**df2.iloc[0])
1 loop, best of 3: 467 ms per loop

In [371]: %timeit df.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key',axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.55 s per loop

In [372]: %%timeit
     ...: df3 = df.join(df2)
     ...: df3[df2.columns] = df3[df2.columns].ffill()
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 1.9 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks Jez, do you have a preference?

Comment: I think first is faster, because numpy.

Comment: What is size of dataframe?

Comment: ~ .5 - 1 million rows, ~50 columns.

Comment: Give me a sec, i add timings.

Comment: I add it now ;)

Comment: Thanks Jez. I'll use these :)

Comment: If your `df2` is a `pd.Series` object instead of a 1-row `pd.Dataframe`, use the third solution `df3 = df.assign(**df2)` but you can drop the `.iloc[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Use `merge` with assigning a dummy key.

```
df.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   one  three  two    a    b    m    u
0  1.0   10.0  4.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
1  2.0    3.0  3.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
2  3.0   22.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
3  4.0    1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0  4.0
```